# Sign "+" is not get inside ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to launch an `ajax` :

```
var tel = "+26132".concat($('#tel_id').val());
    var donne = "num="+tel;
    var ret = $.ajax({
            data: donne,
            type: "POST",
            url:  "<?php echo HTTP_AJAX ?>service/verifierTelAjax.php",
            async: false
         }).responseText;

    if ( $.trim(ret) == "oui" )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
```

When I debugged then I see that the `num` **post** variable does not have the "+" sign when the ajax script is called !

So how to make the sign "+" be gotten ?

Comment: you need to escape it  with a forward slash `\+`

Comment: I tried `var tel = "\+26132".concat(...` but it did not work !

Comment: Before the ajax call is made, can u check if the plus sign available ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let jQuery format it for you automatically for you if you pass the data as an object

```
var donne = {num:tel};
var ret = $.ajax({
        data: donne,
        type: "POST",
        url:  "<?php echo HTTP_AJAX ?>service/verifierTelAjax.php",
        async: false
}).responseText;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
data: {num: tel}
```

To apply URL encoding.

Or manually: `var tel = encodeURIComponent("+26132".concat($('#tel_id').val()));`